# there any way of implementation flutter with smart card reader?

Tags: flutter, dart, smartcard-reader

The smart card is about national Id Card or similar to ATM card

To read the smart card data via dart **Flutter** and also can use in Android/iOS (type-C smart card reader)
I get some SDK/lib but it's native library from Java or Swift. but My purpose is I want the Flutter lib/SDK that working in Android/iOS

It their any library or solution to read the card without native code

Answer (score -1):

You can try using blinkId, which has some great documentation and is easy to implement in your app. You can get the documentation from here https://microblink.com/identity/identity-document-scanning/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).